# Lightning Web Components - Radio button "checked" not retaining when navigating back and forth

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, radio-button, lightning-radiogroup

I am not UI/UX person and I need help with setting radio button as checked when used in a LWC inner template-for-loop which involves page navigation and conditional rendering. I am able to get the selected value in my JS controller, but when I navigate back to the previous page, the "checked" property is not retaining although I still have the selected value. It might be easy to understand if you can look at the sample here:-
[Sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/QWa-zfwxW/16/edit)

The reason I went with custom component for radio group is due to applying CSS to individual radio input.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind the checked attribute of the radio group to your data (e. g. via adding a checked property to your options object) in order to keep track of the selected dom element.

Updated your example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/QWa-zfwxW/60/edit)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much!!